# Return to section context after a subsection

Tags: formatting, typing

There is a coherency problem in the following text (its typesetting). The last paragraph must not be considered as a part of subsect02. For instance it is a kind of conclusion of two approaches covered under two previous subsections. How can I make the reader distinguish it from paragraph(s) related to the last subsection?

```
\section{section}
Some text here about what we are going to discuss.
\subsection{subsect01}
Text about this subsection.
\subsection{subsect02}
Text about this subsection.

Some text here, which is not related to subsection02, but to the whole section.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple approach is to give all of your subsection text a left indent, and possibly a right indent, to set it off slightly from the main section text. Any text starting at the normal left margin would then be identifiable as belonging to the main section.

Comment: And possibly bullets, if your subsections are one paragraph each.

Comment: In my case subsections are several paragraphs long and using either indentation or bullets will make the output a bit ugly by putting a blank area at the left side of the page.

Comment: No, that blank area isn't ugly. It's judicious white space. Don't fear the blankness. I promise it will not bother your readers.

Comment: Indentation is a common and natural delineator for identifying related content. It helps readers to identify the relationship between your content. I agree with Lauren, "don't fear the blankness"!

Answer (score 1):

You could label the section `Conclusions` add a divider that separates it from other sections.  See this question on [long underscore to divide sections of text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/38578/4301) on different options.  This should sufficiently differentiate from the other `\subsections`:

[image]

Comment: +1 for making it another subsection.  Many tools that use semantic markup won't let you create the kind of structure proposed in the question; while tools don't always dictate style, in this case I would take that as a hint.